Angular : BehaviorSubject on props attribute (@Input)
I'm asking if the following code is the best way.
Context
mesures is given by the parent component
The child component must apply some check each time mesures changes.
Component
export class OngletMontantsPrevisionnelsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() mesures: Mesure[] = [];
  mesures$ = new BehaviorSubject<Mesure[]>([]);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    /** Initialisation des mesures manipulées par ce composant */
    this.mesures$.asObservable().subscribe(() => {
      this.checkMontantsPrevisionnels();
    });
    this.mesures$.next(this.mesures);
  }

  private checkMontantsPrevisionnels(): void {
    this.erreursMontantsPrevisionnels = [];

    // Vérifie que 250€ <= cumul HT prévisionnel <= 3000
    let sumMontantHTPrevisionnel = 0;
    this.mesures$.getValue().forEach((mesure) => {
      ...
    });
    ...
  }

  ajouterMesure() { ... }

  supprimerMesure() { ... }



In your opinion, is it the best way ?
Thanks for your help


Directly subscribing to BehaviorSubject: You are subscribing to
mesures$ directly inside ngOnInit(). While this works, it's not the
most common approach. Usually, you would subscribe to the observable
where you're using it, rather than subscribing within the component
itself.

Avoid getValue() inside check function: Instead of using getValue()
inside checkMontantsPrevisionnels(), you can directly access the
value of mesures$ as it's already a BehaviorSubject.

Initializing BehaviorSubject with initial value: You're manually
setting the initial value of mesures$ using next() inside
ngOnInit(). Instead, you can directly initialize it with the initial
value of mesures by passing it as an argument to the BehaviorSubject
constructor.




export class OngletMontantsPrevisionnelsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() mesures: Mesure[] = [];
  mesures$ = new BehaviorSubject<Mesure[]>(this.mesures);
  private mesuresSubscription: Subscription | undefined;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.mesuresSubscription = this.mesures$.subscribe(() => {
      this.checkMontantsPrevisionnels();
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.mesuresSubscription) {
      this.mesuresSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  private checkMontantsPrevisionnels(): void {
    this.erreursMontantsPrevisionnels = [];

    // Vérifie que 250€ <= cumul HT prévisionnel <= 3000
    let sumMontantHTPrevisionnel = 0;
    this.mesures$.value.forEach((mesure) => {
    
    });
  
  }

  ajouterMesure() { /* implementation */ }

  supprimerMesure() { /* implementation */ }
}




When you want to update measures input make sure you create a new shallow copy like so on the parent
// do on parent when you want a refresh to happen
this.measures =[...this.measures];

When you change the reference of the array angular considers the input as changed and fires the hook ngOnChanges
ngOnChanges() {
    this.checkMontantsPrevisionnels();
}

You don't need the behaviour subject for this scenario, just work with plain arrays, but you can always call .next() on the hook to trigger the same!
